# pdflatex does not see an .sty file, but it's installed.

Tags: packages, sidecap

I've installed texlive-scheme-full, but for some reason, for a single package (so far), `sidecap.sty`, pdflatex gives me the error:

```
File `sidecap.sty` not found.
```

I then manually enter the output of `locate sidecap.sty`:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sidecap/sidecap.sty
```

and pdflatex finishes normally. Oddly, if I use other packages in the directory `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/`, pdflatex has no trouble locating them. Any idea what the problem could be here?

My current workaround is to just copy the `sidecap.sty` file into my current working directory, but this is a very hacky hack.

I'm running Fedora 26, if that matters.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you try issuing `mktexlsr` (with super user privileges)?

Comment: Are you sure it is finding stuff there and you don't some how have two latex installations? What does `kpsewhich article.cls ` say?

Comment: look in the log file of your document the full path will be shown to (say) article.cls, is it in /usr/share?

Comment: egreg's suggestion (`mktexlsr`) fixed the problem. Thank you!